# Real elliptic curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

Is it true that the full automorphism group of a real elliptic curve is $T\rtimes\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ where $T$ is either $SO_2(\mathbb{R})$ or $SO_2(\mathbb{R})\times\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$? If 'yes', is there a reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The references is Silverman's book on [Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves](https://books.google.at/books?id=JWHaBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA103&lpg=PA103&dq=automorphism+group+of+elliptic+curve&source=bl&ots=QlSmpI6uNG&sig=m6tdQfSLCcQiQMdPkjz8LBf4eNo&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjQlfn3ztHJAhXB7BQKHVpXDCYQ6AEIYjAI#v=onepage&q=automorphism%20group%20of%20elliptic%20curve&f=false) - $Aut(E)$ depends on the $j$-invariant. It is the translation group $T$ semidirect product with $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ if $j\neq 0,1728$, and $T\ltimes \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ for $j=1728$, and $T\ltimes \mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$ for $j=0$. This is valid for all fields of characteristic not $2$ or $3$.

Actually, in Silverman $Aut(E)$ of an elliptic curve $E$ is defined so that it is a finite group, namely $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ if $j\neq 0,1728$, and and $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ for $j=1728$, and $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$ for $j=0$.

Comment: Do there exist automorphisms of order, for example, 6 (preserving 0) defined over $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: $Aut(E)=\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$ only for elliptic curves with $j$-invariant zero.